# Error 403: Forbidden when trying to make a POST API call

Tags: c#, soap, certificate, soapui, x509certificate2

I have a Dot Net application, built with C# and MVC. I have to use a SOAPUI API, but I'm getting an error 403 when trying to perform this, even though I have access to a P12 certificate and its password. I've pasted the code below, having skipped any unimportant parts.

```
public string anotherPostDataAttempt()
{
    try
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2
             (@"C:\Users\...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\...\certificateFile.P12", "thisIsThePassword");
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(True);

        string url = "https://...";
        //HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        string xmlString = "";
        StreamReader f_read = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\testFile.xml");
        xmlString = f_read.ReadToEnd();
        f_read.Close();


        string DataToPost = xmlString;

        String result = "";
        String strPost = "RequestXML=" + DataToPost;
        StreamWriter myWriter = null;
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
        //objRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //objRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        objRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        try
        {
            myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
            myWriter.Write(strPost);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
        finally
        {
            myWriter.Close();
        }

        //The program crashes on the line below
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

For the record, I've already consulted [this blog post in the subject matter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426121/Send-a-private-client-certificate-p12-in-HTTP-Post) but I'm guessing I must be doing something wrong after all, or I wouldn't be getting this error.

Full error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
InnerException: Null.
Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Comment: More details added. Sorry about that. Also check the code for the relevant comment to see where it crashes

Comment: ok..this means when you sending your data to serverside then on serverside something went wrong so debug your server code

Comment: Alright, is there anything in particular I should watch? The XML file/structure? C# code? Program crashes as soon as it hits that certain line. Before that everything looks good.

Comment: it may be a error of data or xml format or may be other so you have to debug from start of that function

Comment: also can put try catch for batter information about error while debug

Comment: I've already debugged from the start numerous times, but have little more to report than what I've already said. I suspect it might have something to do with the xml data/format though. On the other hand I copied that XML bit from the partner that provides the API, so unless they screwed up it seems unlikely. Thanks for the guidance though

Comment: Hey, I am getting the same error. Did you get the answer. Because, this post is too old and I think you would have got the answer. If so, please suggest me what you did.

Comment: @Vikash I have not. At the time I was switched to another project and I don't know what came of it, truth be told. I suspect it may have had something to do with the certificate being incorrect.

Comment: @Vikash Ah, well can you post it below as a reply then? I'm curious myself and I'm sure others are as well. I'll mark it as an answer of course.